# How to parse *time.Time from sql in golang?

Tags: go, sqlite

Using `gorm` and `go-sqlite3`.  Opening my db using `gorm.Open("sqlite3", "/dev.db?charset=utf8&parseTime=true")`.

Trying to execute

```
db.Raw("SELECT * from users;").Scan(&users)
// models.User has a deleted_at column that is of the type *time.Time
// I am getting Scan error on column index 1: unsupported driver -> Scan pair: []uint8 -> *time.Time
```

How do I parse sql into *time.Time?

User struct

```
type User struct {
    ID        uint64 `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name      sql.NullString
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time
}
```

Comment: How is your users defined?

Comment: Does [this issue](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/18#issuecomment-29351315) do any help for you ?

Comment: @holys Unfortunately, no.  I believe that is a solution for those using a `mysql` db.

Comment: Does the `parseTime=True`  case-sensitive?

Comment: @holys Just tried with `?charset=utf8&parseTime=True`, no luck.

Comment: Is it intended that you are converting `DeletedAt` into a pointer `*time.Time`? Did you try to change it to `time.Time`?

Comment: What is the schema in SqlLite?  And what do the rows look like when you do a query like that from the command line?

Comment: How is the table `users` defined in SQL? Tell us the output of `.schema users` from the sqlite3 shell.

Comment: @iltempo `*time.Time` is used because `DeletedAt` is `NULL` until the user is deleted.

Answer (score 8):

lib/pq implements a [NullTime](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/b269bd035a727d6c1081f76e7a239a1b00674c40/encode.go#L521) type for that. It defines a scanner interface for a time.Time type that may be null. You can use it in exchange to `*time.Time`.

```golang
type NullTime struct {
    Time  time.Time
    Valid bool // Valid is true if Time is not NULL
}

// Scan implements the Scanner interface.
func (nt *NullTime) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    nt.Time, nt.Valid = value.(time.Time)
    return nil
}

// Value implements the driver Valuer interface.
func (nt NullTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if !nt.Valid {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return nt.Time, nil
}
```